# Uk refusal for today, what should i do?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image]

What can i do now? It was denied because of my account overflow and now we fix it and re-applied this is what i got.

Comment: Hi Abiodun. Please read the answers to the question linked, which will explain why applications like this are usually rejected, and how to make them better.

Comment: @Abiodun Olukoya UKVI expects transparency in an applicant’s financial circumstances. They have also seen every conceivable variant of attempts to portray those circumstances in a more favourable light than they warrant. Some things can’t be ‘fixed’. Don’t waste your money on more applications because you will not be visiting the UK any time soon.

Comment: @Traveller, How long can i have them wait before they apply for another visa? Kindly reply

Comment: @Abiodun Olukoya How long is a piece of string? You’re not paying attention to the answers you’ve already had. I don’t mean to sound flippant but with two refusals already, there’s no point at all in reapplying for the foreseeable future. If you keep chopping and changing information on the applicant’s employment and financial circumstances, and trying to massage bank balances, they might even refuse on deception. Or Immigration Rules 320(11) on frivolous applications https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal

Comment: @Traveller, I like your sense of humor, but i was thinking of waiting for 6 months before i apply for them.

Comment: @Abiodun Olukoya Go right ahead if you don’t mind wasting the application fee.

Answer (score 3):

You are not refused because 'of your account overflow' or it's removal, but because you overall history *does not give a convincing picture* that you would leave the country, and be able to pay for yourself while you are there.

Note that your overall history does not disappear by fixing a number and moving money it or out of an account, it simply becomes longer and even more unconvincing.

You need to consider how to make a convincing argument that you will leave the country, and not check off boxes on a list and adjust account balances. Simply imaging yourself in the position of the officer - what would you consider convincing evidence that you plan to return, and what is only 'window-dressing' to make it look like.

Comment: Please refrain from answering clear duplicates but vote to close instead.

Comment: Will do. Searching and linking to duplicates is next to impossible in the App (I'm on an iPhone).

Comment: Upvoted because @Aganju's answer adds an additional and useful perspective.